# Error while reading system.properties variable in log4j2.xml

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

My log4j2.xml looks like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>

        <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/${sys:logfilename}.log" filePattern="logs/${sys:logfilename}.log">
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="max" max="10"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}]> %-5p - %m%n"/>
        </RollingFile>

        <Async name="ASYNC">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Async>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>

        <root level="debug">
            <appender-ref ref="LogToConsole" level="info"/>
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="debug"/>
        </root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I am setting system.properties variable like -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
---some code
System.setProperty("logfilename", "a_cool_logname");
---somecode
}
```

But when i run with this set up I get error like -

ERROR Unable to create file logs/${sys:logfilename}.log java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

I also tried RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${main:-logfilename}.log" filePattern="${main:-logfilename}.log"> in this case log file is getting generated with name logfilename.log . Its not substituting the value set up in main method.

Any idea, where am I making a mistake?

Kind Regards,

Abhi

Comment: It looks log4j2 config is loaded before your class. Did you try if that property is set as a parameter when executing JRE? Also you may try using a static block {} with System.setProperty()

Comment: I tried RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${main:-logfilename}.log" filePattern="${main:-logfilename}.log"> in this case log file is getting generated with name logfilename.log . Its not substituting the value set up in main method.